# Are algorithm questions asking for pseudocode acceptable?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

For instance, if I ask for an algorithm in pseudocode to compute GCD by the Euclidean algorithm in $\textbf{Z}[\sqrt{7}]$?

Comment: In my experience, most questions in MSE asking for algorithms are questions from on-going programming contests.  If I found proof that such a question was from a contest, I would vote to close it.

Answer (score 6):

Algorithms for *mathematical* problems are part of mathematics. A standard way to present algorithms in the *mathematics* literature is via pseudocode.

Thus, there is no a priori reason why this should not be acceptable.

However, the standard rules for asking questions apply. For example if the entire question would read:

> Write pseudocode to compute GCD by the Euclidean algorithm in $\textbf{Z}[\sqrt{7}]$.

Then this would not be suitable question.

If the question reads something like this instead:

> I am trying to understand and possibly will implement the computation of GCD via the Euclidean algorithm in $\textbf{Z}[\sqrt{7}]$. I understand the Euclidean algorithm over the integers and implemented it some time ago. I also feel I understand the idea of the algorithm in principle. However, I have difficulty to pin down the details of {more details}.
>
> Thus, I am looking for a *detailed* description of the algorithm, if possible as pseudocode, only taking for granted basic arithmetic operations?

Then I'd be surprised if there were objections. Something in between would likely still be considered as alright.

A key point for this type of question is to avoid giving the impression that you want others to do your work (rather than just asking for help in doing your work.)